# xelatex does not pick up a .png file

Tags: graphics, xetex

Consider this code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{imageA.png}
%\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{imageB.png}                                                                                                                                      
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compilation works fine with `pdflatex`. With `xelatex` however `imageA.png` is displayed blank while `imageB.png` appears normally.

I don't see any warnings what might be wrong with `imageA.png` nor anything specific in the `.log` files. Nor do I see any warnings referred to in [Why can't XeTeX handle this dank meme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273265/why-cant-xetex-handle-this-dank-meme)

Any clues?

Comment: use the --nopdf option to xetex, so it makes a xdv file then run xdvipdfmx on the xdv to get the pdf, that way you will see any warnings from the dvi driver, which are usually hidden

Comment: I run `xelatex figcheck.tex --nopdf ` but cannot find any xdv file

Comment: It should be `xelatex --no-pdf figcheck.tex`

Comment: I see `figcheck.xdv -> figcheck.pdf
[1]
50837 bytes written` butthere are no warnings.

Comment: Run `xdvipdfmx -vv figcheck.xdv`

Comment: I don't see any difference from `xdvipdfmx -vv figcheck.xdv` for `imageA` and `imageB`

Comment: Perhaps something broken with `imageA`. As a last resort I would import it in Gimp and re-export it.

Comment: Could it be of help to indicate that the troublesome png image has been downloaded from http://vveckaln.web.cern.ch/vveckaln/colour_flow/Rivet/merged_22August_corr_on/pull_angle/Rivet/DeltaRTotal/charge/allconst/ShowPlot.php?pic=pull_angle_allconst_Rivet_leading_jet_:_2nd_leading_jet_DeltaRTotal_4j2t.png

Comment: The dpi of that image is **way out** (3dpi) if it was loaded at that scale it would be from here to infinity (toy story joke actually = 155.67 inches !) the default is usually 72 or more likely 96 dpi = 4.86 inches which will fit on the page

Comment: @KJO, how to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this download works for you in XeLaTeX

[image]

Odd values for dpi can be a problem with different formats such as bmp or png often downloaded by right click from the internet.

In windows 10 folders you can add columns for horizontal and vertical resolution I cant remember if that changed from earlier versions.
[image]
MS paint will also show the problem file properties as 3 dpi x 3dpi but an image with no dpi might on some systems appear as 96 (the default). If you right click download an image with no dpi it will likely also fail.

For a fuller description of a similar problem in XeTeX and an old  workaround using MSpaint to save as/re-save as see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463610/170109

Depending on your needs to modify images during beamer compilation you may find this answer of interest https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455862/170109

Comment: What did you change and how?

Comment: Using ifanview on windows simply set dpi to 96 many graphics packages will do similar and likely one of your repertoir of programs could given the right parameters.

Comment: Why is this an issue only for `xelatex` but not for `pdflatex`?

Comment: Unsure others may answer, but XeLaTeX may be more strict in using the ratio stated by the image, has been similar issues for  pdfLaTeX users when not aware of the possibility

Comment: How do you check the dpi of an image?